# Posting user's ssh keys to github using python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I'm trying to automatically setup git system and I'm stuck in a process where I want to add user's key using the github api. This is what I've so far.

```
USER_SSH_PUB=glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/temp.k.pub')) 
user_Ssh_Pub_Key_File=open(USER_SSH_PUB[0],"r")
GITHUB_URL='https://api.github.com/users/abc/keys'
key_Data=urllib.urlencode({"title":"abcd","key":user_Ssh_Pub_Key_File.read()})                            
request=urllib2.Request(GITHUB_URL,key_Data)                                                         response=urllib2.urlopen(request)                                                                     |
print response.read()
```

I get a 404 when I do this. Has anybody done this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to take a public key and add that to a User's set of keys, i.e., through [this API](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/).

The problem is that you can only do this for the authenticated user, you can not do this on the behalf of a different user. So your `GITHUB_URL` would have to be `https://api.github.com/user/keys` and you would have to authenticate as user `abcd` in order to do that.

I don't think there are any python wrappers for the API using urllib2 which work (well), but there are a few listed [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) which includes [mine](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) which is pip-installable. With my library, your code would look like:

```
from github3 import login

g = login('abcd', password)
with open('~/.ssh/temp.k.pub', 'r') as fd:
    key = g.create_key('abcd', fd)

print("Created {0}".format(key.title))
```

There are other popular wrappers like [pygithub3](https://github.com/copitux/python-github3) but I'm not familiar with them.